# how to continue after the nested model forms railscasts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed the railscasts nested model form part 1, making some changes to have it work in rails 4. Basically, I created 3 models: Quiz, Question, and Answer, and they all belong_to the model intuitively above them. A form in the `new` action is used to create the quiz itself.

However, I'm at a bit of loss on how to proceed now. After creating the quiz, the `show` view looks like this:
[image]

done by iterating through `@quiz.questions` and `@quiz.questions.answers` and just displaying them on the page with their respective `content` attributes.

That's great for displaying just the questions and answers, but it doesn't accept user input at all. How do I make it so the user can use radio buttons to select an answer, and have it submit SOMEWHERE to save the results for grading and future reference for the user?

I've actually tried to create a form simply within the `show` action and have it save to another model but I got stuck extremely quickly. I'm finding it really difficult to both display the results AND accept user input for the displayed results. I also can't figure out a good way to save this data. Making another 3 models with the equivalent of Questions having something like a user_answer attribute seems difficult to implement and messy. I'm a beginner of the grandest caliber so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Nachime, your data model is good so far from what I can tell. Now you will want to link the `answers` to the `users` via many-to-many relationship. Note: this assumes that users will only take each quiz once.

Your next data model version will have a `users_answers` table containing `user_id` and `answer_id`. You can access the relative models using the [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association so that each `user` `has_many :answers, through: :users_answers`.

The quiz will essentially just link the logged in user to the array of answers selected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm not sure if that's the best idea because of a few reasons:  

1. I do want users to take each quiz multiple times. 
2. I don't know how using many-to-many relationships will let me integrate user input. This is the main problem I'm struggling with.